# Compound whereField query in Firestore (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I have been struggling writing the desired query for some time now. I have a collection where every document holds two attributes: **user1** and **user2**. Now I want to retrieve all documents that have specific strings under **user1** and **user2**. The input strings depend on actual use case of my application.
Here is an example:
input strings: "Alex", "Adam"
There are two options of valid documents which I want to retrieve:

1. **user1**: "Alex", **user2**: "Adam"
2. **user1**: "Adam", **user2**: "Alex"

So I need this exact query: Give me all the documents where **user1** is equal to "Alex" AND **user2** is equal to "Adam" OR **user1** is equal to "Adam" AND **user2** is equal to "Alex".

I have been trying multiple queries such as:

```
.whereField("user1", in: ["Alex", "Adam"].whereField["user2", in: ["Adam", "Alex"]
```

I thought this would work because it's saying get documents where **user1** is equal to either "Alex" OR "Adam" AND **user2** is equal to "Adam" OR "Alex". But turns out that you cannot use the in filter more than once in a single query. How would I get this working?

Here is a screenshot of my Firestore database:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this pod for more convenient work

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
```

**First way**

**If you want to get all chats with these 2 users**
For this, you need to add new cross-field with all users in this chat

```
let searchTerm = channelReference.whereField("users", arrayContainsAny: [ID1, ID2])
```

**Simple way with 2 differeent queries -  user1: "Alex", user2: "Adam"**

```
let searchTerm1 = reference
            .whereField("user1", isEqualTo: "Alex")
            .whereField("user2", isEqualTo: "Adam")

let searchTerm2 = reference
            .whereField("user1", isEqualTo: "Adam")
            .whereField("user2", isEqualTo: "Alex")
```

Documentation reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

Comment: Yes correct but those are two separate queries. I was wondering how could I do first case OR second case in one query.

Comment: SO you need a query where user1 is equal to Alex OR Adam AND user2 is equal to Alex or Adam?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create chat and retrieve messages from these 2 users. I also try to walk this way but didn't find to way merge 2 references as you need and found another solution. https://prnt.sc/u4vo2b here you can see a user array of all user in this chat, and now we can write only one query find all chats with this users like this in the answer above. I updated the answer

Comment: Exactly. I used to have the same structure as you included with the **users** array instead. But as I was reading the documentation for the **arrayContains** filter it said: "Similarly, use the array-contains-any operator to combine up to 10 array-contains clauses on the same field with a logical OR." Meaning that in this case it would retrieve the documents having and array of **users** which include "Alex" OR "Adam" is that right?

Comment: With this method, I got all channels for the specific user1. If one of the items in the array is a user1 - than this channel is needed to be shown. I am wrong? or it is what do you need?

Comment: What I need to do is this: I have a function where I want to check if a conversation between two users already exists in the database. Meaning that It either doesn't exist (I retrieve 0 documents) or it exist (I retrieve one document). But with **arrayContainsAny** I retrieve also documents where only one of the two users is included in **users** array am I right?

Comment: So I need a query that says: Does a document where **user1** is "Adam" AND **user2** is "Alex" OR **user1** is "Alex* AND **user2** is "Adam" exists

Comment: in propositional logic: ("Adam" ∧ "Alex") ∨ ("Alex" ∧ "Adam), is this possible with Firestore?

Comment: Okay. You can create 2 references like we talk earlier, and check them on isEmpty. 2 queries. Like ref1.isEmpty && ref2.isEmpty.

Comment: I belive that wouldn't entirely work. Imagine two people again "Alex" and "Adam". Let's say that Alex has 5 conversations existing but none with Adam. Adam has no active conversations yet. So ref1 for Alex !isEmpty and ref2 for Adam isEmpty. But yet they don't have a conversation together. Edit: Oh are you referring to the approach without the **users** array?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about 2 different references like in the Simple way section in my answer. Find all when searchTerm1  is all when (user1 = alex and user2 = adam), and searchTerm2  is all when (user2 = alex and user1 = adam). Get all data bt these queries and check which is empty. Without arrays. Just compare the result of searchTerm1 and searchTerm2

Comment: Yes so I have tested this and it works. Unfortunately having to do two queries each time seems very inconvenient, because each time it has to go through all the documents twice. In the future with possibly tens of thousands of documents I am not sure that this is the right approach.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations it looks like this is impossible. The best way is to create arrayContains and get all chats with user1 and all with user2. After that find the intersect on your side. It will be 1 search (not ideally but 1).

Comment: I almost feel like a better way to do it would be retrieve all the senders conversations regardless of the current receiver and after that see if there is a conversation with the receiver existing.

Comment: So when you are trying to get all conversations on user2 you know the user1? You can get all conversation. For example: now you are user1, and you need all conversations with user2. You can retrieve all conversations with user1 and check in which user2 exist too. What do you think?

Comment: Just retrieve all in which you are exist and find in which user2 exists too on your side. I think it is what are you look for

Comment: I think that this approach is the best one. I will retrieve all the conversations in which I participate and then locally check if one of those also include the receiver. Because realistically you will maybe have 100 conversations in total tops.

Comment: Hope  I helped you!